# Disable cardano address generation on transaction

Tags: wallet, cardano-node

I have instances of `cardano-node` and `cardano-wallet`.

Can you tell me how to disable auto-creation of an address for each transaction?

I understand that it is not safe, but I need to do it for tests.

Comment: Am I correct in understanding that this is not foreseen because it is contrary to [EUTxO](https://docs.cardano.org/plutus/eutxo-explainer)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same address over and over. There is nothing such as auto-creation. The safety for Shelley addresses is the same.

Comment: I think the OP is referring to the auto selection of a change address.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would have to manually calculate the change and provide the change back to the same address as an output to the transaction when using the cardano-wallet transaction builder API.